# Javascript call a function and do not call it again until it has returned

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a button that when clicked calls a function - this function does some asynchronous Ajax and alerts a messagebox when the Ajax has returned. I do not want the user clicking on the button multiple times - if he clicks on the button when the Ajax has not returned then an error message should be alerted.

I know that this can be easily done using a global boolean variable (set it initally to true, make the ajax call and set it to false - set it again to true when the ajax returnes - check if the global is false when the user clicks the button). Also it can be done similarly if instead of the window/global object I use another global object containing the function and the boolean

However, I do not like very much the above methods - I think that they are a little old-school-Javascript. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it, for instance using JS closures !

Comment: why not disable the button when clicked? and when the response is returned, enable it back.

Comment: Agreed - that's another way however I prefer the more elegant one :)

Comment: Why don't you simply disable the button and tell the user that it's processing the request? That way the user will know that something is happening in the background, and you neither need global variables or closures for that. Why should the user be forced to click the button again in the first place. Remember - always provide feedback to the user. Cheers.

Comment: Wow, I'm not the only one to think along these lines. I hate the mobile web. No updates. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this method, your variable will not leak to the global scope. There's no way to manipulate this variable from outside the function:

```
var foo = (function(){
    var pending = false;
    return function foo(){
        if(pending) return;
        pending = true;

        //...Code

        //When finished:
        pending = false;
    }
})()
```

Others may suggest setting a property of the function, but this property can easily be adjusted from outside, which is not desirable.

Comment: Shouldn't function foo() be called somewhere ?

Comment: I have only defined `function foo`. You can call `foo()` whenever you want, but only one function will run at a time. I've only sketched a working concept for you, which can be tweaked to fit in your project. Hence the dummy-names (`foo`).

Answer (score 1):

```
var callback = (function()
{
    var executing = false;
    function yourfunc()
    {
        if(executing) return; // exit if pending
        executing = true;

        // here send the request

        // edit: when the ajax response has returned
        xxxx.onreadystatechange....{
            // do what you need to do with ajax data
            executing = false;
        };
    }
    return yourfunc;
})();

callback();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, you're not assigning `yourfunc` to `callback`, but `yourfunc` to a private variable `cb`.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous function has the form

```
(function(){}))()
```

The last () provides the parameters for the anonymous function.

In the above sample script ( by wes ) returns error as callback is not a defined function. Rob's method using closure sounds good.

Cheers.. Sree